# Question on Furstenberg topology on Z and P subspace of primes

Tags: general-topology, prime-numbers

Hi all I was given this question: I have Z (the integers) with the Furstenberg topology on it, i.e. the topology induced by non constant arithmetical progressions presented [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furstenberg%27s_proof_of_the_infinitude_of_primes), and I am asked to "explicitly" give the subspace topology of P (the primes) within Z, and also the closure of P in Z with the hint of using Dirichlet's theorem on primes to find the closure.

Here is my effort:

For the first part I have the usual basis of arithmetic progressions of integers and by a well known theorem I know the intersection of every basis element with the primes, the new basis is indeed a basis for the subspace topology on P within Z but they say "explicitly", is there anything simpler than this or a nicer presentation I can give?
As for the second part I know that closure could be defined as the intersection of all closed sets in Z containing the primes P. One problem though: I cannot identify the closed sets let alone those that contain P and I am unable to see the connection with he hint on Dirichlet's theorem of primes. So yes the second part is where I am really stuck

Thank you all helpers

Comment: Can you explain where you are stuck?  Do you not understand the wording of the problem?  Is there a particular term you are stuck with?  What have you tried to look at so far?  You really should give more details about what you're stuck with, right now your question reads as though you expect someone to provide a complete solution (because you don't indicate any effort on your part).

Comment: I am sorry @ErickWong now I have added my effort attempts and corrected my post and thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Thank you, this is a huge improvement!  (downvote changed to upvote)

Comment: @ErickWong appreciate the positive feedback and lesson for the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, one can give a nicer description of a base for the relative topology on $P$.

- HINT: Let $p\in P$; what is $p\Bbb Z\cap P$?

For the second part of the problem, let’s ask what integers are *not* in $\operatorname{cl}P$. An integer $a$ is not in the closure of $P$ if there is a $b\in\Bbb Z$ such that $(a+b\Bbb Z)\cap P=\varnothing$. Dirichlet’s theorem tells you that if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, then $(a+b\Bbb Z)\cap P$ is infinite, so we need to look for some $b$ that is not relatively prime to $a$; how about $a$ itself? Then $a+b\Bbb Z=a\Bbb Z$; if $a$ is composite, are there any primes in $a\Bbb Z$? (Be a little careful here: there are actually two cases, one in which $a$ is, so to speak, *really* composite, and one in which it’s simply by definition not prime.)

Comment: Thank you @Brian I got the second part completely but I still have a problem I cannot understand the nicer basis as your hint still is not clear to me Could you please elaborate further?

Comment: @zbigniew2015: Can you answer the question in the hint?

Comment: yes I can. Assuming pZ is all integer multiples of p then the intersection is obviously the singleton consisting of p itself.

Comment: but I still cannot see how this can be used to simplify the basis as you are telling me Could you go one step further with me please?

Comment: @zbigniew2015: Not quite: it’s $\{-p,p\}$, since the underlying set is all of $\Bbb Z$. This tells you that $\{-p,p\}$ is open in $P$. If by $P$ you mean the set of positive primes, it tells you that $\{p\}$ is open in $P$, which therefore has the discrete topology.

Comment: Yes sir my instructor told us that for this course the primes are only the non negatives. Then the answer to your question is the singleton p alone then any prime number singleton is open on its own which is a basis for the discrete topology as every singleton is open Thank you kindly @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @zbigniew2015: You’re very welcome.